# Changing file locations in Python shell?

Tags: python, batch-file

When using the python shell, how can I change to lets say, C:\etc.? I have a batch file that changes to the shell, and I want a way to change it back.

Comment: What do you mean by "change"? Change the working directory? Run a subprocess? Exit the python interpreter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python interpreter has a file path pointing to the location where Python is installed unless you launch it from another location (i.e. from terminal/batch-file/file explorer/application) then it will take the location of that instead.  If you want to go to a file location you must program it.

The [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) module can do what you want.  It provides extensive file/folder manipulation including changing dictionary using `os.chdir()`.  Both full paths and relative paths are supported.

For example:

```
>>>import os
>>>os.getcwd()
'C:\\Users\\Username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32'
>>>os.chdir('C:/ect')
>>>os.getcwd()
'C:\\ect'
```

You can delete and rename files using this module as well.

Comment: Python does nothing to change the working directory at startup. It depends *entirely* on how it was run, such as a shortcut or .py script run from a file explorer window, or running `python` in a command-line shell. The working directory is set when a process is created via `CreateProcess`. If not set explicitly, then it's implicitly set to the working directory of the parent process.